# sed: replacing \n by default

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

I have a file, part of which I am greping into a variable in shell script. In this variable I am trying to replace part of the string through sed. But it is somehow replacing 'newline' as well.

Here is the script

```
#!/bin/bash

str=$(grep "my_stat" $1)

str=$(echo $str | sed -e "s/x/\./g")

echo "$str"
```

My str after the grep looks like this:

```
mystatx1x2x3 10 
mystatx3x4x5 20
mystatx4x4x1 100
```

but after the replacement of "x" to ".". It is changing to like this:

```
mystats.1.2.3 10 mystat.3.4.5 20 mystat.4.4.1 100
```

Any idea why is it happening like this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not say `grep "my_stat" $1 | sed 's/x/.g'` instead?  Note that you don't to escape the `.` in the replacement string; the use of `-e` is superfluous here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
str=$(echo $str | sed -e "s/x/\./g")
```

with

```
str=$(echo "$str" | sed -e "s/x/\./g")
```

but instead of `grep` then `sed`, you could have said

```
sed -n '/mystat/s/x/\./gp' $1
```

Comment: without quote, newline inside variable `$str` will be treated as IFS instead of new line character

Answer (score 0):

do your replacement in one shot

`sed -e '/my_stat/s/x/\./g' file`